# Listening for the record create event

Tags: lightning, lightning-events

I have a custom component which shows all tasks on the case. Now whenever a new task gets created by log a call then I would like to refresh the developed custom component to reflect the newly created task.

Is there any way to listen for the record create event in lightning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever Standard Components do job , they fire refreshView event. You can create a handler which listens to that event and refreshes your component individually.

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInitInCustomComponent}"/>
```

SRC:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DDaqIAG

As gNerb suggest you should prefer using Lightning Data Services as they handle such changes quite brilliantly few people have encountered bugs while capturing refreshView events.

Comment: I suspected something like this but couldn't find any documentation, I believe you're correct, but even the documentation you linked doesn't actually support your claim.

Comment: updated links. Couldnt not find the link in Lightning Component Guide. But Found it in forum. I swear I had read in Component Devloper guide, :/ Thanks

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thank you, yes you are correct it is firing the refreshView event when I add activity. I have a lex console application and in that if other child record gets created (custom object) then this event is not firing.  I assume its an application level event but not sure why it is not firing for related records.  This helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide the "log a call" button and replace it with a custom lightning component that can fire a custom app event that your task component can respond to.